# Open an asp.net application in minimised mode

Tags: javascript, asp.net, process

I have an asp.net application that uses window.open to launch the start page with some defined size. I need to open this application with other console application in a minimised mode. The way I hve tried is defined the start up info (window style as minimised ) and used the process class of .net framework.

This way is not working for launching this application in a minimised mode. While on other hand any other IE process is working fine with the same code logic. Is it failing because my application uses window.open method to start. Please help to start this process in a minimised mode.

Regards
Josh-007

Comment: void OpenWithStartInfo() { ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe"); startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized; Process.Start(startInfo); startInfo.Arguments = "www.abc.com"; Process.Start(startInfo); }

Answer (score 0):

You can't control "minimize". Minimizing is a tool for some desktop environments in some operating systems, it has nothing to do with the browser.

Comment: This way we can minimize any process.                 void OpenWithStartInfo() { ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe"); startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized; Process.Start(startInfo); startInfo.Arguments = "www.northwindtraders.com"; Process.Start(startInfo); }